# ¿Como puedo hacer este slider?

Tags: html, css

Buenos días como puedo hacer este tipo de slider que es como un carrousel pero hay contenido que no se ve hasta que cambia?? un saludo espero me puedan ayudar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¡Hola! ¿Qué has intentado hasta ahora? Deja el código que has ido intentando para poder ayudarte en el punto al que has llegado u orientarte si vas por mal camino :)

Comment: Hola, vaya! lo borre todo porque fue un desastre jajajaj, creo que lo que no se como plantearme es como hacer que el html se queden los laterales partidos @Rabegi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Puedes usar un plugin JS como slick, descárgalo de aquí: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/#go-get-it

El modo que necesitas es "Center", puedes configurar más eventos si así lo deseas. También según si usas o no un framework CSS, puedes darle más o menos un estilo similar a las cards.

```js
//Playing with Ken Wheeler Slick carousel
$('.slider').slick({
  //dots: true,
  infinite: true,
  centerMode: true,
  centerPadding: '12%',
  slidesToShow: 3,
  speed: 500,
  responsive: [{

    breakpoint: 992,
    settings: {
      slidesToShow: 1
    }

  }]
});


/* $(".slick-center").addClass(
  "switch");
$(".slick-current").prev().addClass(
  "switch");
$('.slider').on('init', function(currentSlide) {
 console.log(currentSlide);
 $(".slick-center").prev().toggleClass("switch"); 
}); */
```

```css
button {
  z-index: 102;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  background: #FAFAFA;
}

.slick-slide {
  transform: scale(1);
  //opacity: .5;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out all;
}

.slick-slide.slick-center {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1.08);
}

.switch {
  background: #000;
}

.slider {
  //max-width: 1024px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  ///border: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
  &:after,
  &:before {
    content: "";
    background: #FAFAFA;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 12%;
    z-index: 100;
    //opacity: .9;
  }
  &:after {
    right: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
  }
  &:before {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  }
}

.img-box {
  padding: 0;
  img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

article {
  border: 1px solid;
  float: left;
  margin: 50px 45px;
  font-size: 0.8vw;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<section>

  <div class="slider">
    <div>
      <article>
        <div class="col-xs-5 img-box">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/400x200" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-7">
          <h1>1</h1>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corrupti quos iusto praesentium, vitae officia similique, quo sapiente obcaecati modi quia laborum facere. Aut odit fugit architecto aperiam nam distinctio, debitis!
        </div>
      </article>
    </div>
    <div>

      <article>
        <div class="col-xs-5 img-box">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/400x200" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-7">
          <h1>2</h1>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corrupti quos iusto praesentium, vitae officia similique, quo sapiente obcaecati modi quia laborum facere. Aut odit fugit architecto aperiam nam distinctio, debitis!
        </div>
      </article>
    </div>
    <div>

      <article>
        <div class="col-xs-5 img-box">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/400x200" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-7">
          <h1>3</h1>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corrupti quos iusto praesentium, vitae officia similique, quo sapiente obcaecati modi quia laborum facere. Aut odit fugit architecto aperiam nam distinctio, debitis!
        </div>
      </article>
    </div>
    <div>

      <article>
        <div class="col-xs-5 img-box">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/400x200" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-7">
          <h1>4</h1>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corrupti quos iusto praesentium, vitae officia similique, quo sapiente obcaecati modi quia laborum facere. Aut odit fugit architecto aperiam nam distinctio, debitis!
        </div>
      </article>

    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: Woowww muchas gracias! no espera una respuesta tan completisima, voy haber si le doy yo estilos ahora para dejarlo como quiero, muchísimas gracias @AMCode

Comment: para eso estamos bro

Comment: puedes ayudarme con la configuración @EMCode intento hacerlos más grande pero si los hago se me descentran

Comment: Crea la nueva pregunta @Miguel y luego pegas el enlace aqui mismo como comentario para ir a verla

Comment: Por favor evita responder preguntas que no muestran un mínimo esfuerzo por parte del OP. Contesta preguntas bien formuladas [Como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @x3k_js jajajaj me has echo reír. You win this time!